# string having '<br/>' throws unterminated string literal js error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xhtml

I am fetching some data from Db and displaying it in a textarea using jquery in the following way.
`$('#textareatest').val('<% =teststring %>')`.It is possible that the string 'teststring' can contain XHTML line breaks(`<br/>`).whenever the string contains `<br/>` I am getting the `'unterminated string literal'` error.I saw a number of posts considering '\n' as line breaks and suggesting to escape it.I tried to escape the `<br/>` similarly,but it didn't work.

Could someone please help me with this?

**UPDATE:**: I've already escaped single quotes.
here is an example string ***test string`<br />`***

Thanks.

Comment: What if teststring contains a single quote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very possible that if `teststring` contains a line break (`"\n"`) that it will throw that kind of error because the JavaScript engine would see that as

```
$("#textareatest").val('Some random text
then an unexpected linebreak');
```

I would recommend either ensuring that the `teststring` does not contain a line break or escaping it.

It's also possible that if `teststring` contains any single quotes it will terminate the string:

```
$("#textareatest").val('Some random test's but that single quote kills the string');
```

Comment: though there was no '\n' in the data obtained from the db,when I tried to debug the js in firebug I saw '\n' being added to <br/>.So I had escaped it and that solved the problem.thanks for the help.

Comment: Thank you, you saived my day! I had a PHP function which outputted a \n in the string contained in a Javascript block and this was the reason why I continued to get 'unterminated string literal'!

Answer (score 1):

It would help a lot to see an actual example, but it's going to be something silly and annoying.  My guess would be that you're mixing single and double-quotes in your code in a way that ends up with an unmatched outer set as you construct the string.

**Update**

Well, if that's the exact string you're sending, then it's no problem -- there's nothing to the string literal that's a problem, so you must be mistaken -- there's no error.

Assuming the code persist in not working even after I've told you that, then you probably need to look more deeply.

Look, the error message is pretty clear -- you have something that starts out syntactically as a string literal, but where the interpreter can't find the end.  There's really only one syntax for string literals, to quote:

> A string literal is zero or more
>   characters enclosed in double (") or
>   single (') quotation marks. A string
>   must be delimited by quotation marks
>   of the same type; that is, either both
>   single quotation marks or double
>   quotation marks. The following are
>   examples of string literals:
>
> "blah" 'blah' "1234" "one line \n
>   another line" In addition to ordinary
>   characters, you can also include
>   special characters in strings, as
>   shown in the last element in the
>   preceding list. The following table
>   lists the special characters that you
>   can use in JavaScript strings.
>   Character Meaning \b  backspace \f    form
>   feed \n   new line \r carriage return
>   \t    tab \  backslash character
>
> 4.5. Escaping characters
>
> For characters not listed in the
>   preceding table, a preceding backslash
>   is ignored, with the exception of a
>   quotation mark and the backslash
>   character itself.
>
> You can insert quotation marks inside
>   strings by preceding them with a
>   backslash. This is known as escaping
>   the quotation marks. For example,
>
> var quote = "He read \"The Cremation
>   of Sam McGee\" by R.W. Service."
>   document.write(quote)
>
> The result of this would be
>
> He read "The Cremation of Sam McGee"
>   by R.W. Service. To include a literal
>   backslash inside a string, you must
>   escape the backslash character. For
>   example, to assign the file path
>   c:\temp to a string, use the
>   following:
>
> var home = "c:\temp"

At this point you need to do at least one of two things:

- read the code carefully, or better yet walk through the code with someone else, looking for the errant single or double quote
- put `console.log` statements through your code to narrow down where the error is occuring.

The biggest thing to remember is that the parser is always right -- even when you think it's wrong, it's still right, because you can't negotiate with a parser.

Comment: please check the update in my original question to see the example string.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit of overkill, but just to test: does

```
$('#textareatest').val(decodeURI('<% =System.Uri.EscapeUriString(teststring) %>'))
```

work?

This will encode the entire string for use in URLs, and let javascript decode it.  It's not very efficient, but it is rather safe (since the set of characters allowed in a URI is pretty small).

Comment: `System.Uri.EscapeUriString` doesn't seem to encode single quotes (`'`)

Answer (score -1):

You should encode the html string, so `<br/>` becomes:

```
&lt;br/&gt;
```

Comment: Because that won't cause an unterminated string literal error. NB I'm not one of them...

Comment: Agreed, but with single quotes already being escaped, and based on the test string provided, it's something that should be done either way...